# Designing a python3 For loop that assigns cell values from two columns of an Excel sheet to variables in a Selenium process and loops for all rows

Tags: excel, python-3.x, loops, selenium, for-loop

Sorry, not sure my title is the best but here's my problem in a little more depth. My core issue here is being quite new to programming in general and not grasping the logic behind For loops well enough to apply them to specific situations.

I have a sheet with data in two columns:

Column A = PO number
Column B = Tracking number

I would like to take the values A1 and B1 and use them in a single Selenium process and then this process loop for A2 and B2, A3 and B3, etc. for all rows with data in them. Here's the relevant bit of the Selenium process I'd like to integrate the cell values into:

```
import (selenium modules)
import openpyxl

workbook = load_workbook('/my/path/Tracking.xlsx', data_only=True)
worksheet = workbook.active

for row in cell_range:
    for cell in row: 
        value = cell.value #this is where I'm stuck pulling A1 & B1 properly and then knowing how to pull the next row in the following loop

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('www.myurl.com/Tracking/POD?=&tracknum=' print(str(B1)) '&lan=en')

driver.save_screenshot('/my/path/POD_for_PO_' print(str(A1)) '.png')
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont see where `cell_range` is defined. Also, a for each loop is fine if you include your selenium operations in it, but not for each cell in row, if you're only taking two that is (A1 and B1). thirdly i think you don't want to `print(str(A1))` but simply append the string like so: `...' + str(A1) + '...` to say for sure id need at least the definition of `cell_range` and any other parts of the script that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:
`from selenium import webdriver
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    workbook = load_workbook('Tracking1.xlsx', data_only=True)
    worksheet = workbook.active
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    for row in worksheet.rows:
        cellNo=0
        for cell in row:
            if cellNo==1:
                A1 = cell.value
                print(A1)
                cellNo = 1
            else:
                B1= cell.value
                print(B1)
        driver.get('http://www.myurl.com/Tracking/POD?=&tracknum='+B1+'&lan=en')
        driver.save_screenshot('POD_for_PO_'+A1+'.png')`